# CSS for textarea make textarea height span the height of the first line?

Tags: html, css

How can I make the textarea height match the height of the textarea as if it only had one row. It would essentially look like a text field. The nonreuseable way is by playing with the height attribute and making the textarea look like it only spans one row, but is there a reuseable way?

When I use the CSS attribute height: auto, it spans two rows.

Comment: Cloud you please explain it by jsfiddle or any kind of image markup, so that i can give you better suggestion, what do you want exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the rows attribute

```
<textarea rows="1"></textarea>​​​​​​​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/5t4n9/)

Doesn't seem to work in firefox though, and in many browsers the user can simply resize a texarea.